# str_replace when used with an array replaces single character strings incorrectly in PHP

Tags: php, str-replace

Forgive me for my wording of the question. It could be that `str_replace` is replacing these characters as it is supposed to and that I don't properly understand the fundamentals of what going on. However here is my question.

I'm trying to use `str_replace` to create a function in PHP that replaces abbreviated names with full version of the names. The problem is that in some cases the abbreviations are single letter abbreviations and this causes problems. For example:

```
<?php
//Abreviated Set Names
function changer($string_to_replace){
    $ab_name   = array('A','APP','ANG',);
    $full_name = array('Alley Cat', 'Apples', 'Angela');
    return str_replace($ab_name, $full_name, $string_to_replace);
}

echo changer('APP');
?>
```

When I call this function and pass it A i will return `"Alley Cat"` which is what I want it to do. However, if I pass it `"APP"` instead of returning `"Apples"` it returns `"Alley CatPP"`. Obviously not what I want it to do. I've searched around quite a bit and have not been able to find a solution for this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Kind Regards
Sour Jack

Comment: Why would `str_replace` work correctly on an array, or work at all ?

Comment: @adeneo Because it's documented to work with arrays.

Comment: user http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php

Comment: I got the idea for the function from a similar function that a gentleman used to replace state abbreviations with the full state name. State abbreviations are never composed of a single character though.

Comment: Your input says to replace `A` with `Alley Cat`, and that's what it did.

Comment: @Barmar - oh, it actually is, didn't know that! How strange? PHP...

Comment: It has nothing to do with single characters. You'd have the same problem with `$ab_name = array('AP', 'APP', 'ANG')`.

Answer (score 0):

Benoit (and everyone else).

Thank you for your answers. I also found this code which after testing works very well.

```
<?php
$state = 'AVR';
echo convert_state($state);

function convert_state($key) {
    $a2s = array( 
        'A'=>'Apples',
        'AVR'=>'Abby Road'
    );
    $array = (strlen($key) <=3 ? $a2s : array_flip($a2s));
    return $array[$key];
}
?>
```

Comment: Also note, the $array variable can be modified to accomodate different string lengths by changing the value following the <=